# Why are my URIs not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my routes.php I have :

```
$route['default_controller'] = "bitcoin";
```

and in my config.php I have:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/bitcoin/';

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

here is my controller: http://www.pastie.org/2253458

When I try to go to the following, I get a 404 not found (but the 404 template looks different):

```
http://localhost/bitcoin/edit/
http://localhost/bitcoin/index.php/edit
```

Comment: Is your application folder located at the root, or is it in a folder called bitcoin?

Comment: Do you have a controller named edit or a controller named bitcoin?

Comment: what if you go to http://localhost/index.php/bitcoin/edit ? I'm guessing your htaccess isn't set up properly.

Comment: the application folder is in a folder called bitcoin, and I have a controller named bitcoin.php within the controllers folder. Will post .htaccess asap

Comment: my .htaccess file just says: 
Deny from all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say if you've removed or not your index with .htaccess, but if you didn't, did you try using:    `http://localhost/index.php/bitcoin` ?

Or better, since it's your default controller, just `http://localhost` ? 
What you're doing is quite strange, I can't understand if you're in a subfolder called bitcoin (in case, it should be `http://localhost/bitcoin/` to call the default controller, which is also called bitcoin but doesn't need to be indicated in your URL).
If you're in root, You should rewrite your urls as: `http://localhost/index.php/bitcoin/edit` to call the `edit()` method of your default controller

**Edit:**

If you're in a subfolder called bitcoin, your base url, with default controller, should be:
`http://localhost/bitcoin/`  (which is the same as `http://localhost/bitcoin/index.php/bitcoin`)

If you want to get the bitcoin method edit(), should be `http://localhost/bitcoin/index.php/bitcoin/edit`

Also, try removing your .htaccess AT ALL and see what happens.

**Edit2**

Oh, one last thing: use CI_Controller and not CI_controller, if you're on a OS where lowercase matters you might encounter some problems

Comment: i am not in root, and am in a sub-folder called bitcoin

Comment: Ah, that seems to work - when I do http://localhost/bitcoin/index.php/bitcoin/edit

but why won't it work when I do 
http://localhost/bitcoin/bitcoin/edit

When I upload this, I don't want people to have to see somesite.com/bitcoin/index.php/bitcoin/edit when I just want them to see somesite.com/bitcoin/edit

Comment: Well, as for removing the first bitcoin, you should just take all into root. As for removing index.php, you can grab the basic and working example provided on CI's user guide

Answer (score 2):

You can't access functions through the default controller like this.. It's assumes your trying to access another controller. Default controller is used when nothing is passed, ie: index.php

You will need to go to /bitcoin/index.php/bitcoin/edit

And note you will only be able to go to /bitcoin/bitcoin/edit if you have a htaccess file setup for routing.